# Eclipse CTRL+SPACE deletes text

Tags: java, eclipse

Somehow the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> handling in Eclipse changed twice in the last weeks when existing text stands after positions in which we use it.

Let's say I want to create a BufferedReader for a file:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(something.filename);
```

Now I notice this doesn't work and I want to create a FileReader:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader[CURSORPOSITION]something.filename);
```

However when I now hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> and choose the FileReader constructor from the list and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, "something." (the part up to or including the space) gets deleted.
Did this behaviour change recently and is it configurable?
I remember being amazed that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> handling somehow got better with a recent update but it seems it didn't last.

Comment: Have you tried downloading a fresh copy of Eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

You have probably selected 'Completion overwrites' radio button on the **Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist** screen. 'Completion overwrites' overwrites whatever follows the cursor position. The other option is 'Completion inserts'.